# MATLAB: How to change x-axis scale with dateticks

Tags: matlab

I try to plot unemployment over time but years are displayed in 10 year frequency. I want to have x-axis ticks every 5 years but can't seem to manage this as xticks are not in dateformat

Below is the relevant code if you want to take a look.

```
clear;

X=xlsread('UNRATE.xls');%Import Data 
s_year=1950;
e_year=2015;
X=X((s_year-1948)*12+1:(e_year-1948)*12+12);
startdate = datenum('01-1950','mm-yyyy');
enddate = datenum('12-2015','mm-yyyy'); 
dt = linspace(startdate,enddate,792);%create numeric dates 
plot(dt,X);%plot data against dates 
datetick('x','yyyy');%format dates in display
recessionplot; 
title('Unemployment Rate in the US over time');
xlabel('Year'); % x-axis label
ylabel('Unemployment Rate'); % y-axis label
```

Answer (score 3):

When working with time series, the best you can do is to manually modify the `XTick` property of the axis so that it fits your needs once the plotting has been performed. For example:

```
%...

plot(dt,X);
set(gca,'XTick',datenum(1950:5:2015,1,1));

%...
```

Working example:

```
clear;

s_year=1950;
e_year=2015;
X= rand(792,1);
startdate = datenum('01-1950','mm-yyyy');
enddate = datenum('12-2015','mm-yyyy'); 
dt = linspace(startdate,enddate,792);

xticks = datenum(1950:5:2015,1,1);
xlabels = cellstr(num2str(year(xticks.')));

figure();
plot(dt,X);
set(gca,'XTick',xticks);
set(gca,'XTickLabel',xlabels);
```

Output:

[image: Output 1]

Original plot without ticks adjustement:

[image: Output 2]

Comment: That was helpful. The problem is the data are in months so if I step every 5 years I do not get the correct scale. Could I circumvent this somehow?

Comment: I edited my answer with a full example. Do you confirm this is not producing a correct result for you?

Comment: It does not recognise year in line 11: 
Undefined function 'year' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Error in Untitled3 (line 11)
xlabels = cellstr(num2str(year(xticks.')));

Comment: Thanks for your input and example anyway.

Comment: What Matlab version do you have? Year has been introduced in 2014.

Comment: In case, use `xlabels = cellstr(num2str((1950:5:2015).'));` instead of `xlabels = cellstr(num2str(year(xticks.')));`. But the only true perceived difference comes from the fact that `XLim` property must be adjusted too and I didn't perform this operation.

Comment: The xtick problem is fixed, the x-axis is still not as expected but no worries. An image is below in my answer. I just started using MATLAB so not sure how to fix these but this is helpful insight. Many thanks!